# Preventing a web-page from getting hit from another server

Tags: ddos, content-security-policy

A DDoS attack may result from a website attempting to access the resource of another website. For instance, `example.com` (attacker) is trying to access resources on `example.net` (victim).

The information which I have gathered till now is:

1. If `example.com` tries to access the resources on `example.net` by embedding the site in an **`<iframe>`**, `example.net` can mitigate it using the [**`X-Frame-Options`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header.
2. If `example.com` tries to access the resources on `example.net` using **XHR**, `example.net` can mitigate it using the [**`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header.

In the above cases, `example.net` is still being hit by `example.com` even though the content is not being served. Are there any W3 standards or mechanisms which can be used to prevent `example.net` from getting hit in first place?

Comment: Can you define "getting hit" a bit better?

Comment: @NeilSmithline "Getting hit" means if the server is bothered, i.e. if the browser prevents the attack on its own or it bothers the server with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is inherent in the system and you will never be able to really prevent this. What one can do to prevent the inclusion of images in other domains is to process every request and check the `referer` header for the source domain. When you enter a URL in your browser an press enter the broweser will first download the HTML file and then will download all the ressources of this file including all the images linked by `img` tags. As these resources aren't directly downloaded the browser will add the URL of the originally called webpage as a `referer`.

How this can be implemented relies on the server-side-technologie you are using.

Comment: I believe that it is easy to [spoof referer headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing) so I'm not sure how this helps.

Comment: It helps because the the "attackers" in this scenario are usual users that are visiting a website that includes the externaly included images. Spoofing a referer isnt done unintenrional and you cant spoof someone elses referer without access to his system.

Comment: Thx. I understand now. I don't think this answer really solves the problem as the server will still receive all of the requests in order to do the `referer` filtering. I believe that the OP is looking for something that doesn't involve their server doing the filtering.

Comment: The problem ist that there is no such solution^^

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to ask, but I'll try to answer to the question I think that you might be asking.

As long as web technologies allow fetching resources from other domains this kind of DDoS attack is possible. Even if the remote server doesn't serve anything back, it must process the requests (eg. uses server resources). This kind of attack would require that malicious site has enough visitors to overwhelm the target server with traffic. This is basically like the [slashdot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect), but happens w/o the user knowing that the browser is fetching stuff from the target site.